# Excel Classifying based on satisfying requirements

Tags: excel

I am having trouble trying to classify some data as "Excellent", "Good", and "Poor" based on a few other requirements.

Snapshot of my Worksheet:

[image]

Column P is where the labels will be placed.

-Excellent is classified as having a value above 0 in at least 3 of 4 of the Shipping Rebate cells (G16:J27) **AND** as having a value in the overall Sales volume bonus (M16:M27)

-Good is classified as having atleast 2 of the 4 **OR** as having a value in the Sales Volume Bonus

-Poor is classified as meeting none of the requirements for Good or Excellent.

Can anyone show me how to create a formula to check for those requirements and then label them?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter this formula in `P16` and drag it down:

`=IF(AND(COUNTIF(G16:J16,">0")>=3,M16<>0),"Excellent",IF(OR(COUNTIF(G16:J16,">0")>=2,M16<>0),"Good","Poor"))`